# just after ng new I had : crbug/1173575, non-JS module files deprecated

Tags: angular

I just create a angular project with : ng new testProject, I chose scss.
When I launch the project with ng serve, I have this error : crbug/1173575, non-JS module files deprecated.

I did not write anything in the project. I just ng new and ng serve, so I do not have import who can cause this error.

I use chrome, and I do not have pluging in it.

Can you help me ?

Thank you !

I tried ng serve --host 127.0.0.1, it worked, but I would like, to make it work with ng serve, because I have this error on all my angular and Ionic projects

Comment: report it as an issue on [github](https://github.com/angular/angular)

Comment: I did this yesterday, and they replied, that I need to ask my question on stackoverflow...